# How do I set a checkbox to unchecked based on php var - previous posts don't fix my issue

Tags: php, html, checkbox

I have a php var ($testx) set to 0.

Html code looks like this:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='test_cb' id='test_cb' checked=<?= $testx == true ? 'checked' : '0' ?>></input>
```

The checkbox is always checked even though the php var being checked is false.  I must be missing something obvious.

Comment: Don't set the value of the `checked` attribute, include the `checked` attribute if needed, and don't include it if not.

Answer (score 3):

You're close :)...

```
<input type='checkbox' name='test_cb' id='test_cb' <?= $testx == true ? 'checked' : '' ?>></input>
```

Answer (score 1):

First: Don't include the `checked` attribute *unless* you want it checked.  (Your original code includes `checked=` always, even if it should not be checked)

Second: Personally, I find that style of code to be less readable.

Here is how I would propose you do it:

```
<?php $checked = ( $testx ) ? ' checked' : ''; ?>
<input type='checkbox' name='test_cb' id='test_cb'<?php echo $checked; ?>>
```

NOTE: This assumes that `$textx` is either truthy or falsey - since you wrote `$textx == true`, I'm guessing it's either `NULL` or `FALSE` if it's not set.  Clearly you could check more strictly, if required:

```
<?php $checked = ( TRUE === $testx ) ? ' checked' : ''; ?>
```

FINALLY:
Better yet - since this would be something I presume you do often - would be to create an `is_checked` function, like so:

```
function is_checked( $var ) {
    if ( $var ) {
        echo ' checked';
    }
}
```

Then you could use it repeatedly, like so:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='test_cb' id='test_cb'<?php is_checked( $testx ); ?>>
<input type='checkbox' name='test_again' id='test_again'<?php is_checked( $testy ); ?>>
// etc...
```

Comment: I used the first solution to keep me progressing, but thank you for this, as I will certainly move this to a function in the coming days and simplify all future needs in this area.   Nothing like one function to be used repeatedly.